# Display object property in DataTable column of type custom Class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable

i have a DataTable, it consist of columns of type string and custom object of class Node

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Node(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }

}

 <DataGrid Name="data1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" />
```

The problem is I am binding the DataTable to Datagrid. All the entries under the Column Node is displayed as the Complete class name. I want to display the Name property of Node.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve that:

Simple would be to override **`ToString()`** method for class **`Node`** and return **`Name`** property from it.

```
public class Node
{
   ....
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return Name;
   }
}
```

OR

You have to set **`AutoGenerateColumns`** to **`False`** on dataGrid and give your own set of columns.

```
<DataGrid Name="data1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      ..... // Other columns will go here.
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Node.Name}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but suppose my class property is of boolean type, in that case I would like to display a checked column. Any idea how I can do this.

Comment: Yeah second option is a way to go then. You can use `<DataGridCheckBoxColumn/>` for that.

Comment: But I don't know my DataTable columns, they are added at runtime while the dataTable is populated.

Comment: Wait a minute dataGrid is smart enough. If column type is boolean, it will automatically generate DataGridCheckBoxColumn for you. You need not to worry about that.

Comment: Sorry if My question is not clear, what if my column type is of a class which has a property of bool type. Then how should I bind it in XAML. I cannot add columns in my xaml as i dont know what all columns will be there. After doing AutoGenerateColumns as False I am getting empty grid

Comment: If you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False`, you have to provide your own set of columns like i did in my answer. Moreover, if columns are known at run time than create a wrapper DataTable with all nested properties in it and bind with DataGrid.

Comment: Also, please don't ask follow up questions in comments. Originally posted question is already answered. For any new questions, always raise separate question so that other people of community can help you out. No one read the comments. So, please post separate question for this.